# Linear Algebra Library for java

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I have a set of linear equations that have an infinite number of solution (a solution set) but I cant seem to find any Java-libraries that can produce the solution-set (they all complain about the matrix being "Singular", which would produce an infinite set of solutions?).

I may be failing to understand something, but I've looked into some libs as [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) and [la4j](http://la4j.org) but don't understand why they're not able to produce a solution-set for me.

BR Tomas A

EDIT: I've tried solving the set of equations using a "solver" online and it produces the solution-set for me so I know it should be possible.

Comment: have you checked commons math or colt?

Comment: How would any library be able to return an infinite number of solutions?  Why don't you just catch the "isSingular" exception

Comment: The set of solutions is a linear space that's a span of one or more basis vectors. Any linear combination of those basis vectors is a solution to your set of equations. Your question reduces to: "I've got a matrix representing a set of equations, how do I get the basis vectors out of it". Once you realize this, your question becomes a math question and is off-topic here.

Comment: This question belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Kuba Ober, and for the record I've asked a similar question on math.stackexchange.com and they helped derive the linear equation-system, problem was I couldnt find any way of getting the solution-set. Thank you for the rephrasing of my question, I can probably find my way from there. Post it as an answer and ill mark it.